# SUM of column based on bitwise op condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table

```
|ID  |Types|Amount|
|-----------------|
|1   |1    |12    |
|2   |3    |3     |
|3   |4    |5     |
|4   |5    |2     |
|-----------------|
```

`Types` is a value based on bitwise OR of type values.

Lets say:

- Type0 is 1 (1<<0)
- Type1 is 2 (1<<1)
- Type2 is 4 (1<<2)

What i would like to achieve is `SUM` of Amount grouped by types.

The result of this table should look like this:

```
Type0: 17 (12+3+2, from ID 1,2,4)
Type1: 3 (from ID 2)
Type2: 7 (5+2 from ID 3,4)
```

Is it possible to do it in single sql transaction?

Comment: You lost me at 12+3+4 ?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry sorry fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use union to create a table for your bitmasks if you don't already have one(you should create one in my opinion, but that's not the point of this answer) and then use bitwise logic to join them together, then group by the type_name in order to get totals by each type.

```sql
SELECT
    type_name
  , SUM(Amount)
FROM (
    SELECT 'type 0' AS type_name, 1 AS type_bitmask
    UNION
    SELECT 'type 1',2
    UNION
    SELECT 'type 2',4
) AS derived_types
JOIN [Your amounts table] AS amounts_table
    ON
    amounts_table.Types & derived_types.type_bitmask = derived_types.type_bitmask
GROUP BY
    type_name
```

Note that this can be shortened:

```
SELECT 1<<x.types type
     , SUM(y.amount) total
  FROM 
     ( SELECT 0 types
        UNION
       SELECT 1
        UNION
       SELECT 2
     ) x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.types & 1<<x.types = 1<<x.types
 GROUP 
    BY 1<<x.types
```

Comment: Note that the type automatically gives us the bitmask (1<<type).